# Regular expression in R behaves differently than in other languages

Tags: regex, r

The regular expression pattern `^[A-Z]{2,4}$` specifies that the string to be matched should start with an uppercase letter and end with an uppercase letter. It also requires that there be exactly two, three, or four letters present. Anything else will not be considered valid:

```
filter_symbols <- function(symbols) {
  valid <- regexpr("^[A-Z]{2,4}$", symbols)
  return(sort(symbols[valid == 1]))
  #valid
}
filter_symbols(c("MOT", "CVX", "123", "GOG2", "XLE", "AAPL", "AAPLS", "A"))
```

...and it works like a charm:

```
[1] "AAPL" "CVX"  "MOT"  "XLE"
```

Now when you test the same code here (and there are many similar online regex tester out there):

```
^[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_uQIi2Q-s6HzV4-L)

...you **don't get any match** (neither when you start the words in new lines each) - why is it behaving differently in both cases?

Comment: Because you try to test several words at the same time.

Comment: Note that `"[A-Z]"` is ASCII.  Use `"[:upper:]"` if you want a locale-aware character class.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: This is interesting, I tried to test it in debuggex with umlauts but it didn't work. So how can you set the locale to e.g. Germany?

Comment: And I think that all the letters would need to be upper, rather than just the starting and ending letters. `grep("[A-Z]{2,4}", "AaAaaA")` ... no match.

Comment: Actually this totally looks like stock tickers to me, so ASCII should be fine. Otherwise, use `perl = TRUE` along with the pattern `^\p{Lu}{2,4}$` to get Unicode support

Comment: Use `?Sys.setlocale` to change the (various) locale settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `^` matches at the start of the string, and `$` matches only at the end.

Debbugex and other related sites pass the whole input textarea as a single input string, so your regex actually was being matched against `MOT\ncvx\n123...AAPL`.

Enable the `m` (multiline) flag - in this mode, `^` and `$` will match the start/end of *each line* and it will enable you to test multiple inputs.

See the [updated debuggex demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VtlpQ9X-1mirciF6)

Answer (score 2):

In Debuggex, no match results yield because you don't have the correct modifier turned on.

In most all regular expression engines, the anchors `^` and `$` only match (respectively) at the beginning and the end of the string by **default**. If you want to match the begin/end of each line (*not only begin/end of string*), turn on the `m` (*multi-line*) modifier which causes this behavior.

You can see the difference with this mode modifier being turned on — [**Debuggex Demo**](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vrDisoP2ev55SkMJ)